# Issues with methods parameters...Java

Tags: java, oop, methods

@Rogue Here is the new way that I have it set up...and I am currently getting the "cannot find symbol" error. I double checked and my object (rectangle4) was declared. 
Any ideas why? Thanks again bro...

```
package rectanglewithprivatedatafields;

class RectangleTestFile
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double lengths = rectangle4.getLengths();
    double widths = rectangle4.getAreas();

//rectangle object 4
RectangleWithPrivateDataFields rectangle4 = new RectangleWithPrivateDataFields();
System.out.println("\nUser Specified Rectangle 4");
System.out.println("Please enter the appropriates sizes for your rectangle: \n");
System.out.println(rectangle4.getWidths());
System.err.println(rectangle4.getLengths());
System.out.println(rectangle4.getPerimeters(rectangle4.getLengths(), rectangle4.getWidths())); 
System.out.println(rectangle4.getAreas(rectangle4.getLengths(),rectangle4.getWidths()));
 }//main
}
```

Comment: Include the full error messages. Better yet, read them and see if you can figure out what they are telling you!

Comment: you aren't declaring `lengths` or `widths` anywhere within your `main`. those variables don't exist within that scope. put `double lengths = rectangle4.getLengths();` towards the top of your main. similar for `widths`

Comment: @trooper your assistance is so appreciated

Comment: If I remember correctly `Scanner` will consume the `System.in` stream, don't remake it each time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `rectangle4.getPerimeters(lengths, widths)` did you mean `rectangle4.getPerimeters(rectangle4.getLengths(), rectangle4.getWidths())`?

Your utility class doesn't have any private member variables, only public accessor methods.

Answer (score 0):

`lengths` and `widths` aren't variables in your main method, so make them:

```
int lengths = rectangle4.getLengths();
int widths = rectangle4.getWidths();
```

Since these methods read input, you should only call them once. Additionally from what I remember `Scanner` consumes the `System.in` stream, so I would only make it once. Moving forward (for the sake of object orientated programming), I would make the constructor accept a `Scanner` to build itself, and then have methods which return the values I need:

```
//Simple, short class names are easier to work with
public class Rectangle {

    //length and width is data, or "state" of our rectangle, so store it
    private final int length;
    private final int width;

    //Allow creating it without requiring input
    public Rectangle(int width, int length) {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    //We create ourselves given a Scanner which we can take input from
    public Rectangle(Scanner input) {
        System.out.print("Length: ");
        this.length = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Width: ");
        this.width = input.nextDouble();
    }

    //Calculate based around known information
    public double getArea() {
        return this.length * this.width;
    }

    //Calculate based around known information
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (this.length + this.width);
    }

    //getter
    public int getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }

    //getter
    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

}
```

Thus making the calling of it like so:

```
public static final void main(String... args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //make once
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(input); //let our rectangle do all the work
    //Simple!
    System.out.println("Your rectangle has a width of " + rect.getWidth()
            + ", a length of " + rect.getLength()
            + ", the perimeter " + rect.getPerimeter()
            + ", and an area of " + rect.getArea());
}
```

The critical ideas here being the separation of data and roles - the `Rectangle` will manage all of the aspects of information and creation of itself; whether you provide it the `length` and `width` manually, or if you provide it a means of obtaining that info (our `Scanner`). The `Rectangle` will store the information it needs and return any other information we would want out of it (our methods). This makes the calculations and usage of the class very simple (you pass it input, and now your work is done from an external standpoint).

Comment: like "double lengths = rectangle4.getLengths(); I get an error...It says that "cannot find symbol"

Comment: well, that means there's no `rectangle4` variable

Comment: I have RectangleWithPrivateDataFields rectangle4 = new RectangleWithPrivateDataFields();

Comment: Code has been updated...sorry about the delay, I was at work.

Comment: is there any way that I could pay you to help me with this assignment? I'm in a pretty bad spot and I'm just trying to learn this material. My school doesn't offer tutors and my teacher doesn't have availability for online students. My job keeps me on the road, so I'm screwed.

Comment: you called on the `rectangle4` variable before you declared it